# How to normalize JS Object with special char property

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hey guys I'm working on a project and I'm getting an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "userChoice[language]": "en",
  "userChoice[responses][favColor]": "black",
  "userChoice[responses][favCity]": "new york",
}
```

How do I normalize that? So I can access the properties that I need?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Unless `language`, `responses` and `favColor/City` are variables, that's probably not valid JS. Seeing the real structure helps. 2) What do you mean with normalize? If you want to convert it to some other format, show us the format you're going for and ideally also show us what you've tried to accomplish this.

Comment: Need the format that you expecting.

Comment: Sorry... the format is that except everything is as string. I will update the question.

Comment: What do you mean by _normalise_? You can already access those properties using square-bracket notation, eg `obj["userChoice[language]"]`, `obj["userChoice[responses][favColor]"]`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a es5 approach to normalize the object

```js
function normalisedObject(object) {
    var normalised = {};
    for (var key in object) {
        //regex to capture all [.*] groups
        var matches = key.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
        if (matches) {
            var temp = normalised;
            while (matches.length > 0) {
                //get first key and replace []
                var newKey = matches[0].replace(/\[|\]/g, "");
                if (matches.length !== 1) {
                    //keep traverse if the left over keys are greater than 1
                    temp = temp[newKey] || (temp[newKey] = {}); //assign empty object
                } else {
                    temp[newKey] = object[key];
                }
                //poll
                matches.shift();
            }
        }
    }
    return normalised;
}

//example
const t1 = performance.now();
var object = {
    "userChoice[language]": "en",
    "userChoice[responses][favColor]": "black",
    "userChoice[responses][favCity]": "new york"
};
var normalised = normalisedObject(object);
const t2 = performance.now();
console.log(`Operation took ${t2 - t1}ms`);
console.log(normalised);
```

Answer (score 1):

When an object's keys don't allow you to use simple dot notation, ie `obj.property`, you can use square-bracket notation instead, eg

```js
const lang = obj["userChoice[language]"]
```

But I have a feeling you'd actually like to transform that object into something resembling this

```js
{
  userChoice: {
    language: "en",
    responses: {
      favColor: "black",
      favCity: "new york"
    }
  }
}
```

If that's the case, you need to reduce the object entries (key / value pairs) to a new object, parsing out the key *paths* and building new, inner objects as you go

```js
const obj = {
  "userChoice[language]": "en",
  "userChoice[responses][favColor]": "black",
  "userChoice[responses][favCity]": "new york",
}

const t1 = performance.now()

const normalised = Object.entries(obj).reduce((c, [ key, val ]) => {
  // get the key parts as a path array
  const path = key.replace(/]/g, "").split(/\[/)
  
  // pop the last property for assigning the value later
  const prop = path.pop()
  
  // determine the inner-most object by path
  const inner = path.reduce((o, k) => {
    // create a new object if it doesn't exist
    return o[k] ?? (o[k] = {})
  }, c)
  
  // assign the value
  inner[prop] = val
  
  return c
}, {})

const t2 = performance.now()

console.info(normalised)
console.log(`Operation took ${t2 - t1}ms`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Note that if you start throwing any array properties in, eg `userChoice[foo][0]`, this won't work.